# Scrollbar dont show on Chrome

Tags: css, angular, typescript

The matter is the following, I have a selector and I want to show the scrollbar (I am using ng-select). The point is that using Overflow-y: visible or scroll nothing appears, however in Firefox it does!
I already tried adding a specific height, also a max-height and I get no results. Someone who can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
    <ng-select class="ng-select form-control form-control-solid form-control-lg px-2.5 py-1 text-sm rounded"
        [clearable]="false" [searchable]="false" placeholder="Select a Merchant"
        (change)="storeSelectedMerchant($event)" [ngModel]="(activeMerchant$ | async)" *ngIf="merchants$ | async">
        <ng-option value="all"><b>All Merchants</b></ng-option>
        <ng-option *ngFor="let merchant of merchants$ | async" [value]="merchant.guid">
            <p>
                <strong class="block">{{merchant.dba}}</strong>
                <span>MID: {{merchant.mid}}</span>
            </p>
        </ng-option>
    </ng-select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ng-dropdown-panel {
  background: #eee;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 6px 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);

  .ng-dropdown-panel-items.scroll-host {
    overflow-y: visible !important;

    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 6px !important;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px white(0, 0, 0, 0);
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px white(0, 0, 0, 0);
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px white(0, 0, 0, 0);
      border-radius: 3px;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      border-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
  }
```

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try replacing the  `overflow-y: visible !important`
to `overflow-y: scroll !important`.

Comment: Hi! I Tried but still doesn't work: c

Comment: This one might resize the scrollbar and make it not noticable. try to comment this code.
`&::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 6px !important;
    }`

Comment: Nop, sadly it doesn't work. Yes it can be seen in Firefox but chrome seems to keep hating me

Comment: Maybe this would help, just created using your [HTML and SCSS](https://jsfiddle.net/dcjqaw2p/1/). Works in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking all this time to help me. Unfortunately it still does not work, but at least it has helped me to realize that the problem is elsewhere !! And that is already a lot of time saved, now we just need to find where the problem is xD